# Hello World in Spring is not running

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am a beginner in Spring.
Trying to run a simple "Hello World" project
Using Netbeans IDE 8.1, Glassfish 4.1

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.jsp">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Example :: Spring Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form  method="POST" action="addph">
        <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
        <form:input path="name"></form:input>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

When I run the code, browser cant find the page.
Showing error.
is there anything I am missing?

Comment: And where's your controller?

Comment: Are you using any SimpleFormController?

Comment: can I use SimpleFormController? I thought it deprecated now.

Comment: The <welcome-file-list> is conflicting with your indexcontroller. try to remove it.

Comment: Post your controller.

Comment: @vipin cp Apparently his controller was defined in his xml file. not as java class.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte yeah right.. My mistake. And how welcome file list has got issue? It should work even welcome file has not defined.

Answer (score 0):

set **welcome file** to index.jsp in your web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Actually redirect.jsp is redirecting to the "index.jsp".